# Execute command inside for loop from variable in bash

Tags: bash, shell, variables, loops, eval

Trying to run commands defined in variables inside a for loop:

```
somevar="Bit of text"
cmd1="command \"search '$somevar' here\""
cmd2="command \"search '$somevar' there\""
for cmd in cmd1 cmd2 ; do
    eval \$$cmd
    ssh server1 eval \$$cmd
done
```

I've put in the variations I have to consider such as the ssh inside the loop etc as these are needed in my script.  I think the eval is the right direction, but the way that the quotes inside the command get interpreted comes through wrong.

Comment: Please read [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider this broken example:

```
$ cmd1="touch \"file with spaces\""
$ $cmd1
```

Quoting is handled before `$cmd1` is expanded, so instead of one file this will create three files called `"file`, `with`, and `spaces"`. One can use `eval $cmd` to force quote removal after the expansion.

Even though it uses `eval`, the line `eval \$$cmd` has that same quoting problem since `\$$cmd` expands to `$cmd1`, which is then evaluated by `eval` with the same behaviour as the broken example.

The argument to `eval` must be the actual command, not the expression `$cmd1`. This can be done using variable indirection: `eval "${!cmd}"`.

When running this through SSH there is no need for the `eval` because the remote shell also performs quote removal.

So here is the fixed loop:

```
for cmd in cmd1 cmd2 ; do
    eval "${!cmd}"
    ssh server1 "${!cmd}"
done
```

An alternative to indirection is to iterate over the values of `cmd1` and `cmd2` instead of their names:

```
for cmd in "$cmd1" "$cmd2" ; do
    eval "$cmd"
    ssh server1 "$cmd"
done
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the command that is being run requires those quotes to be passed through intact as they form part of the arguments (command to run a DB query).  I didn't mean "command" as the built in, just the particular command I want to run.

Comment: Works perfectly! At least for ssh to remote host. I just need to have run locally as well. Also, if you can expand on what that is doing I'd appreciate it. Thanks matey!

Comment: @delronhubbard I expanded on the expansions :)

Answer (score 1):

I see two solutions, either you change your loop to:

```
for cmd in "$cmd1" "$cmd2" ; do
    ssh server1 $cmd
done
```

or to:

```
for cmd in cmd1 cmd2 ; do
    ssh server1 ${!cmd}
done
```

Comment: Seems to ignore the `$($cmd)` and just throws a login back.

Comment: Unless you set up an SSH-key, it will ask you the login and password.

Comment: Sorry, key already setup. It gives me a prompt for the remote server, ignoring the command I sent.

Comment: Thanks, Tom beat you to it on that one! But thanks ;)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't understood your question the first time, it's a shame because I thought about ${!cmd}.

Comment: it's a very useful if you could do the whole example in 1 command line

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `eval \$$cmd` you need to use:

```
res=$(eval "$cmd")
ssh server1 "$res"
```

Comment: Thanks, but still doesn't interpolate the strings in the command properly.